# Is there any way to find broken images across an entire site?

Tags: 7, media

A number of images appear to be missing from within body fields of a site. It may have been like this for a while, so it's hard to say why. Folder/file permissions and paths are correct. The site was never moved and oddly, its only happening on some images and not all. Is there any way to detect which ones are missing on an entire site (40,000+ nodes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the [linkchecker](http://drupal.org/project/linkchecker) module.   It does check the source of `<img>` tags in the body, however it doesn't do it perfectly like it does for `<a>` tags.

- If `<img>` have alt text, it thinks it is fine, even though the link is broken
- `<img>` with links like "sites/testing/file/image.jpg" are returned *not* broken, links like "/sites/testing/file/image.jpg" are returned broken
- External links work pretty well.

Your best bet is to use [Xenu’s Link Sleuth](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html) project  (windows freeware)

Additional resources:
Here is a [comparison](http://drupal.org/node/298397) of the link page modules.  Maybe you can find something else.
[Broken Link Checker](http://drupal.org/node/72840) thread on drupal.org

Comment: Looks like Link Sleuth is the one. (Handy little tool)